# Need help using strncpy() in C++

Tags: c++

I am stuck for hours during my assignment. Specifically, on this part:

> The constructor should take a const-qualified C-Style string as its argument. Use the `strncpy()` function from the `<cstring>` library to copy it into the underlying storage. Be sure to manually null-terminate the attribute after you copy to assure that it is a valid C-String (in case the parameter contained a much larger string).

Where am I making mistakes, and how should I change my code?

[image: error message]

```cpp
#ifndef STRINGWRAPPER_H
#define STRINGWRAPPER_H

class StringWrapper{
    public:
        StringWrapper (const char myString);
        
    const static int max_capacity = 262144;
    private:
        int size = 1;
        char myString [40];
};


#endif
```

```cpp
#include "StringWrapper.h"
#include <cstring>

StringWrapper::StringWrapper (const char myString){
    strncpy(StringWrapper::myString, myString, sizeof(myString));
}
```

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "ThinArrayWrapper.h"
#include "ArrayWrapper.h"
#include "StringWrapper.h"
#include <stdexcept>

int main(){
    
    char myString[]{ "string" };
    
    StringWrapper StringWrapper('h');
    
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Review `const char myString`.  What pass a `char` to `strncpy()`?

Comment: Better to post your error message here as text.

Comment: [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) and [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) are open source implementations of the [C++ programming language](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp). So study their implementations of [the string library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string). If you use GCC,  compile with `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` (all warnings and debug info) then use [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) to understand the behavior of your program

Comment: Your constructor does not take a c-string, but a single character instead.

Comment: A `char` is a single character, as opposed to an array of many characters or a pointer to many characters.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Do you really think it's good advice for a beginner to study implementations of the C++ Standard Library?

Comment: @DanielLangr Yes, since OP is basically reinventing `std::string`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch OP is just trying to solve an assignment given to them. Real-world implementations of `std::string` are extremely complicated. They are generic for different character types, they apply short string optimization technique, they use allocators, etc. This is really not easy to understand for beginners.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I will try again.

Comment: @DanielLangr: Why do you believe beginners should not be allowed to look into real-world code? As soon as they are no more students, they will have to contribute to real-world code....

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I didn't say they are not allowed to do that (where did you get this from?). I said it would not be easy for them to understand such code. Just `basic_string` header in libstdc++ have [over 7000 lines](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/basic_string.h).

Comment: So what? Most programmers, when starting their first job, will incorporate a team of developers in charge of more than 10KLOC of code!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, your call to `strncpy` is wrong. Please check the reference regarding the `strncpy` from [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strncpy).

According to the definition of `strncpy` :

```
char *strncpy(char *dest, const char *src, std::size_t count);
```

In your case, you are calling `strncpy` like this:

```
strncpy(StringWrapper::myString, myString, sizeof(myString));
```

Here, `myString` is a `const char` type variable. You need to make it to `const char *`. If you like, you can check my modification of your code from [here](http://cpp.sh/23asv).

Comment: Thank you for the help and it got fixed easily just by adding * like you edited. Do you mind telling me what differences ' * ' make in this case?
I feel like I understood  what & and * do and then I get confused  often when I actually code.

Comment: `char` is a single character, e.g., 'a'. On the other hand, `char *` is a pointer of characters which represents the starting of an array of characters (also well-known as `c-string`), e.g., "aaaa". Do you know the difference between `int`, `int *` and `int []`? This is similar idea for `char` type.

Comment: Thank you again, it helped me :)